# how to get hidden href tag in selenium with "::before"

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

Im trying to get a url from a PLP and visit each of the elements to get certain keywords from the PDP and dump it into json file. However, the list only returns 1 data only. Im suspecting the website is trying to block the action. Im using this program once a month to see what new features are added in new items.

The code between the "***" is the part I am having trouble with. It returns the correct value but only returns 1 data.How can I get more data?In the example below I am only getting the product names to make it simple.

sample url: "https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-running-shoes/7puZ8yzZoi3"

[image]

Actual element

```
<div class="exp-product-wall clearfix">
    ::before
    <div class="grid-item fullSize" data-pdpurl="https://www.nike.com/t/epic-react-flyknit-2-mens-running-shoe-459stf" data-column-index="0" data-item-index="1">
                                    <div class="grid-item-box">
                                      <div class="grid-item-content">
                                        <div class="grid-item-image">
                                          <div class="grid-item-image-wrapper sprite-sheet sprite-index-1">
                                            <a href="https://www.nike.com/t/epic-react-flyknit-2-mens-running-shoe-459stf">
                                              <img src="https://images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/pwp_sheet2?$NIKE_PWPx3$&amp;$img0=BQ8928_001&amp;$img1=BQ8928_003&amp;$img2=BQ8928_005">
```

Below working code

```
import selenium
import json
import time
import re
import string
import requests
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

domain =  'website url goes here'

def prepare_driver(url):
    '''Returns a Firefox Webdriver.'''
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='location to chromedriver')
    driver.get(url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-name ')))
    time.sleep(2)
    return driver

def fill_form(driver, search_argument):
    '''Finds all the input tags in form and makes a POST requests.'''
    #search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('q')
    #search_field.send_keys(search_argument)
    # We look for the search button and click it
    #driver.find_element_by_class_name('search__submit')\
        #.click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-name ')))

def scrape_results(driver, n_results):
    '''Returns the data from n_results amount of results.'''

    products_urls = list()
    products_data = list()

    ***for product_title in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="exp-gridwall-content clearfix"]'):
        products_urls.append(product_title.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//div[@class="grid-item fullSize"]').get_attribute('data-pdpurl'))***

    for url in range(0, n_results):
        if url == n_results:
            break
        url_data = scrape_product_data(driver, products_urls[url])
        products_data.append(url_data)

        return products_data

def scrape_product_data(driver, product_url):
    '''Visits an product page and extracts the data.'''

    if driver == None:
        driver = prepare_driver(product_url)

    driver.get(product_url)
    time.sleep(12)

    product_fields = dict()
    # Get the product name
    product_fields['product_name'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//h1[@id="pdp_product_title"]').get_attribute('textContent')
      #  .text.strip('name')
    return product_fields

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        driver = prepare_driver(domain)
        #fill_form(driver, 'juniole tf')
        products_data = scrape_results(driver, 2)
        products_data = json.dumps(products_data, indent=4,ensure_ascii=False) #ensure_acii => changes japanese to correct character
        with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(products_data)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Desired Output in json:

```
[
    {
        "product_name": "Nike Epic React Flyknit 2",
        "descr": "The Nike Epic React Flyknit 2 takes a step up from its predecessor with smooth, lightweight performance and a bold look. An updated Flyknit upper conforms to your foot with a minimal, supportive design. Underfoot, durable Nike React technology defies the odds by being both soft and responsive, for comfort that lasts as long as you can run."
    },
    {
        "product_name": "Nike Zoom Fly SP Fast Nathan Bell",
        "descr": "The Nike Zoom Fly SP Fast Nathan Bell is part of a collaboration with artist Nathan Bell, featuring hand-drawn graphics that celebrate running as a competition with yourself. It's designed to meet the demands of your toughest tempo runs, long runs and race day with a responsive construction that turns the pressure of each stride into energy return for the next."
    }
]
```

Comment: This should be a fun one. You may have to parse the stylesheets, since the contents of :before elements are populated in CSS: `.myel:before { content: 'http://theurlyoureafter.com' }`

Comment: You probably need window.getComputedStyle for this. So use execute_script or switch to js

Comment: Could I have some example using the existing codes up there? Im not really native with Python yet. Im assuming that parsing the stylesheets needs another function, if so I want to know what I need to import so that I can parse them.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to be rude. I updated my inquiries with the actual code of elements

Comment: Is there an url that can be shared with expected output?

Comment: apologies for amending frequently. Updated the sample url and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the urls with requests. I targeted the data-pdpurl attribute. In the selenium loop you may need to add some handling of requests for location. A short wait is needed during loop to prevent false claims of product not available.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

d = webdriver.Chrome()
results = []

r = requests.get('https://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-running-shoes/7puZ8yzZoi3')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
products = []
listings = soup.select('.grid-item')

for listing in listings:
    url = listing['data-pdpurl']
    title = listing.select_one('.product-display-name').text
    row = {'title' :title ,
           'url' : url}
    products.append(row)

for product in products:
    url = product['url']
    d.get(url)
    try:
        d.get(url)
        desc = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".description-preview")))
        results.append({'product_name': product['title'],
                        'descr' : desc.text})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, url)
    finally:
        time.sleep(1)

d.quit()
print(results)
```